# Can we perform jdbc based AAD authentication to SQL Server in python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, jaydebeapi

I use jaydebeapi to perform SQL Server connection and couldn't figure out how to connect for AAD based authentication.

```
import jaydebeapi
driver_class_name = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
connection_details = 'jdbc:sqlserver://mydb.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=dbname;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;'
user = user
pwd = pwd
dependency_jars = ["/data/jars/mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre8.jar","/data/jars/adal4j-1.6.4.jar"]
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(driver_class_name,connection_details,driver_args=[user, pwd],jars=dependency_jars)
```

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorPyRaisable: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/AuthorizationGrant

Comment: Do you have Java 7+ and JDBC 6+

Comment: @Charlieface Java version is 8 . Unable to determine jdbc version . Any suggestions on how i can locate it on linux ?